# Is it possible to attach application data to a socket?

Tags: c, winapi, winsock2

I'm developing an event driven Win32 socket server in C. In order to control several aspects of the communication process, I need to create a data structure at the moment in which a new connection is accepted, however I haven't found a way to attach my application's data to the newly accepted socket in such a way that by knowing the socket I can efficiently retrieve the connection control data, because of that, every time I receive a FD_READ or FD_CLOSE message I must perform a search operation, but even though the search function is very efficient it still implies an overhead.

I wonder if there is a set of functions similar to SetWindowLongPtr/GetWindowLongPtr which could allow me to attach my application's data to every new socket, that way I could avoid the search operation completely.

**CLARIFICATION:**

I am not looking for a more efficient way to search, the one I'm using is quite efficient, what I want is a way to completely avoid any kind of search operation (if such a thing is possible).

Comment: Because sockets are represented by file descriptors, you can just use a very basic type of global lookup structure.

Comment: How are you multiplexing several sockets ? With WSAAsyncSelect() (in which you could encode an index into the message), select() (in which case you anyway need a linear search), or something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid having to lookup the socket data each time, switch to an I/O Completion Port:

[Windows Sockets 2.0: Write Scalable Winsock Apps Using Completion Ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302334.aspx)

Create an IOCP with [`CreateIoCompletionPort()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363862%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and associate each accepted socket with it, then perform asynchronous socket I/O operations using [`WSASend()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`WSARecv()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741688%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which allow you to pass a custom data pointer with each operation.  Define and allocate a custom `struct` for that purpose.  Then call [`GetQueuedCompletionStatus()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) periodically, such as in a worker thread, and each IOCP notification will give you the `struct` pointer that was associated with the socket operation that completed.

Comment: Thanks, although it was very hard for me to make it work, it took me 2 day to understand the whole process, mainly because all the examples out there are either: too complex, too verbose, poorly explained to the extreme, or missing a key topic. Thanks again!